# Write Drupal Code online

Tags: testing

Is there any website that allows to write and test Drupal Code online ? Like [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) one for PHP [writecodeonline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Simplytest.me](http://simplytest.me/), but that's really for testing existing module to see if you like them (e.g. never used Panels before, select Panels from the list and hit Launch Sandbox to give it a go).

You could set up a test site with Devel and hit *devel/php*.  However this isn't really any different from running a local sandbox site and doing the same thing.

Apart from that, I've not seen anything like what you're looking for.  Sorry :(

Comment: Great ! Somewhat close, i can use node/add/page in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with any public accessible online version, but if you set up a local sandbox install of Drupal and enable the core PHP filter you basically have that.

Comment: devel module does that neatly with a block, but I was looking for an online site